# Populating LINQ Where statement with List<class>

Tags: c#, linq

I am writing a LINQ expression to query an IQueryable.
I would like to populate my .Where claus(es) from a List filled with my custom objects.

```
internal class TheCustomClass
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

I would like the LINQ expression to add a Where clause for every item in the List.

The dynamic result would look something like this:

```
var queryable = enumerable.Where(x => x["name1"] == "value1")
               .Where(x => x["name2"] == "value2")
               .Where(x => x["name3"] == "value3")
               ... and so on
```

Comment: Is `enumerable` just a `List<TheCustomClass>`, because one `TheCustomClass` instance called `x` does not seem to allow the indexer syntax `x[str]`? Or is `enumerable` some nested collection or dictionary?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
TheCustomClass[] filters = ...;
var queryable = enumerable.Where(x => filters.All(f => x[f.Name] == f.Value));
```

Alternatively, you could append a dynamic number of where clauses, but that seems needlessly complex.

If your query is an actual SQL LINQ query, this will not work. If that is the case I'll expand this answer.

---

Per the comments you require IQueryable support. We must use a query shape that can be understood by the provider:

```
IQueryable<Something> q = ...; //initial query
foreach (var f in filters)
 q = q.Where(x => x[f.Name] == f.Value); //apply the filters
```

It looks like your query provider supports the `x[f.Name]` syntax. Is it targeting Lucene/Solr?

Comment: Kudos for the super fast answer. I tried it our and I got the following error: "Unsupported expression node type: Lambda"
My code looks like this:
var queryable = linqQuery.Where(x => x.Language == language)
.Where(x => facets.All(f => x[f.Name] == f.Value))
.FacetOn(x => x["manufacturer"])
.FacetOn(x => x["packaging"]);
var results = queryable.GetResults();

Comment: What ORM are you using? What is FacetOn?

Comment: Fantastic, the last part did it! Thanks

Comment: This is performing a search towards the Sitecore API, the underlying search provider is Lucene but Sitecore abstracts all the search functions in a very nice interface. There is probably a much easier way to do what I have been trying but this was a quick and dirty solution.